# Is it possible to get a list of files opened for add by any user, given a directory?

Tags: perforce

I need to see what users are adding new files in a certain directory depot. Is it possible to do see the users and what they've named their files using `p4 opened`?

I've tried

```
p4 opened -a //depot/MMA/interfaces/STAMP/branches/v16.1/src/testCfg/bundles/...
```

but it appears the command doesn't interpret the `...` as other commands do; probably expecting files only.

Comment: It works on my installation. Are you sure the path exist ? or try a shorter path like `p4 opened -a  //depot/MMA/..." to see if you get any file.

Comment: If the files have already been added and are affecting other users, then they are no longer opened, but submitted. Then you want `p4 changes //depot/MMA/interfaces/STAMP/branches/v16.1/src/testCfg/bundles/...`

Comment: @XavierT. - You were right. It actually works fine. I thought it wasn't working because I was under the impression that at least one of my coworkers had new files they were actively developing. Turns out they were not. Closing this question.

Comment: @AndrewCheong: You can salvage the question by reformulating "How do I get the list of all opened file for add by user in a directory ?" and post your command as an answer. It might help someone googling for it one day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p4 opened -a //<DepotName>/...` works for me. I can also specify multiple directories:

```
bash-3.2$ p4 opened -a //guest/jen_bottom/...
//guest/jen_bottom/P4RubyGem/install.rb#10 - edit change 10688 (text) by jen_bottom@jen_bottom_ws
//guest/jen_bottom/P4RubyGem/install.rb#10 - edit change 10216 (text) by jen_bottom@jen_bottom_ws_home
```

I have found the following bug in the release notes, which may perhaps explain why 'p4 opened is not behaving as expected:

> (#72994) **
>
> ```
>   Certain 'p4 opened' commands could potentially return incorrect
>   results on a server with db.peeking set to 2 or higher.
> ```

Hope this helps,
Jen.